# Angular 2/4 Routing - Set a virtual dir

Tags: angular, routes

I've a routing problem.

I need to use a "virutal directory" in the uri that change in base on some server side logic but i don't know how tell angular route to ignore this part.

Ex: https://www.example.com/[myvirtualdirectorycode]/{all others routers code goes here}

to be more specific:
https://www.example.com/HADS45DFDF/  <-- this must be the application root url, this route is virtual in server side too

www.example.com/HADS45DFDF/Login 
www.example.com/HADS45DFDF/Data/GetData

the [XXX] url part will be used in the server side for perform some validation and in the client side for isolate app instance using JWT auth for each different url path opened.

Really thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your query, you can try something like below

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/:xyz/Login', component: Abc,  name: 'abc' }
    { path: '/:xyz/Data/GetData', component: Def, name: 'def' },
])
```